# .htaccess deny from all to view files but let the files work in other htmls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'd like to ask that how can I make that to deny from all to view ex.: "main.js", "main.css", but thiese files will work after this in other html files?
I did this in that folder:
.htaccess -->

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.
```

At this point no one can view thiese files except the local machine, but thiese files won't be streamed in html files, so there will be a raw html without css and js and so.

Comment: This simply is not possible in a robust manner. This is not how the web works. Look at this from that point of view: you _publish_ those files, the script and the style sheets. So why do you then suddenly want to _not_ have them published? Why should it matter _why_ people download those files?

Comment: You'd either need to use a token based approach and route all such resources through a routing script. That however would slow things down and prevent caching on the client side, adding much load to your server for nothing. Or you could try to implement some rule based on evaluating the referrer header in each legitimate request, but that is not robust, any kid can easily work around that. My suggestion: don't waste time into that.